# How do I change something depending on date?

Tags: javascript

What I need to try an accomplish is to output a specific message depending on how close a date is. The task is to change an element of a web page from a message saying "Renewal Unnecessary" when the date is more than 3 months away, "Renewal upcoming" when the date is less than 3 months away, and finally "Renewal Required!" when the date is 1 month away.
So far I have:

```
if()
   {<hre>Renewal Required!</hre>}
else if()
   {<ha>Renewal upcoming</ha>}
else
   {<hg>Renewal Unnecessary</hg>}
```

I am uncertain of how to write the condition for what I need the script to do, for example the renewal month or date might be the 26th February, and is there some way of making it work off the computers date?

Comment: Your question seems to have been cut off at the end!

Answer (score 1):

Date.now returns currrent date in miliseconds. Just check for

```
renewal_date - Date.now()
```

And compare it with the corrent number of miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it. You could expand this to be considerate of what day of the month it is, also. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/IHiSUYe/1/edit)**

```
var deadline = new Date(2014, 1, 2); //2014, February 2nd (January is Month 0)
var today = new Date();

var monthDiff = deadline.getMonth() - today.getMonth();

if (monthDiff < 3) {
  console.log('Deadline is in 3 months or less!');
}

if (monthDiff <= 1) {
  console.log('Deadline is in 1 month or less!'); 
}
```

**Answering your comment:** There a are lots of ways this can be done - learn the basics. Here are two examples that might help.

```
var p = document.createElement('p);
p.textContent = 'My message here';
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Or if the element already exists on the page:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myElem');
elem.textContent = 'My message here';
```

Comment: how would i get it to output a change to a webpage? like changing a specific message depending on the month.

Comment: @user3139363 adding text to the page output is beyond the scope of your question, but I updated my answer with an example. It sounds like you really need to read a lot of tutorials and get more familiar with the basic concepts and capabilities of JavaScript.